# Average Area of Convex Hull of N points in Unit Hypercube

Tags: expectation, volume, geometric-probability, convex-hulls

Suppose we randomly pick $N$ points inside the unit hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and form their convex hull. What is the expected value of the volume of the convex hull?

For example, in the case $N=n=2$, we are asking about the average length of a line segment in a unit square. This can be shown to be $\frac{2+\sqrt{2} + 5\ln (1+\sqrt{2})}{15} \approx 0.521$.

Is there a method to compute this expected value in general?

Edit: as was made clear to me by a comment, I should clarify that the volume I am asking for is not coming from Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but rather $\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$.

Comment: The answer is zero if $n\ge N$, including the case $N=n=2$. The line segment between two points doesn't have a volume in two dimensions. The first non-trivial case is $n=2$, $N=3$, where the average area of the triangle is $\frac{11}{144}$ (see [Square Triangle Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html) at MathWorld). For $n=3$, $N=4$, the average volume of the tetrahedron is $\frac{3977}{216000}-\frac{\pi^2}{2160}$ (see [Cube Tetrahedron Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeTetrahedronPicking.html) at MathWorld).

Comment: @joriki Ah foolish me. I was mixing my measures. I'll edit the question to get at what I properly wanted to ask.